# How to get members in a Twilio channel?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, twilio, twilio-api

I am not sure if my syntax is right. I am able to initialize my chat client fine, and also able to get the list of channels fine. However, channel.members is coming in as `nil`, so not sure what the issue is. I have verified that there *are* two members in the channel. In fact, this works fine in javascript (`channel.getMembers`).

```
for channel in twilioChatClient.channelsList().subscribedChannels() {
     channel.members.members(completion: { result, paginator in
        ...
     })
}
```

Comment: members.members sounds not so good for me.. are you sure object has such a structure ?

Comment: Yes, the Twilio object structure is sort of weird.